# C# Forms Queue number of button clicks to execute after first finishes

Tags: c#, forms, event-handling, queue, buttonclick

I am not allowed to use threading so queuing only.

as part of our school project we have to implement a working animation which represents an elevator. I have done all the logic and animation behind it ( moving up and down, opening doors, etc.. ), which is controlled by button_click events. 
e.g:
button1- move the elevator up
button2- move the elevator down
button3- open elevator doors
button4- open floor doors

My problem I have is : When i click button1, the elevator will move up, however if I press button2 before button1 finished processing the event, my code will break and all hell breaks loose :)) what i would like to do is to have some sort of logic like this:

-button1 is pressed and is added to the queue,
-button2 is pressed before the button1 finished so it is added to the top of the queue and waits until button1 stops processing, then runs the button2 event

I was looking into the concept of queuing and I found out that is exactly what i need. However, i've tried numerous ways on how to implement this and filed every single time.

It would be most appreciated if somebody could explain with an example of how to do this, where to implement it ( where to actually run this code ) or point me to a good reference about it.

Comment: Google "Command Design Pattern", I think it fits pretty much with what you need to do.

Comment: looks like this is not for a newbie in c#?

Comment: Are you by chance using `Application.DoEvents();`?...

Comment: No, I am not using Application.DoEvents();

Answer (score 0):

There is a `Queue` collection in C#.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
public class ElevatorAction
{
    public string Action { get; set; }

    public void Act()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

// Create two actions (up and down)
ElevatorAction upAction = new ElevatorAction{ Action = "Up" };
ElevatorAction downAction = new ElevatorAction{ Action = "Down" };

// Create the Queue
Queue<ElevatorAction> elevatorActionQueue = new Queue<ElevatorAction>();

// Add the actions from your button click events.
elevatorActionQueue.Enqueue(upAction); // call from button 1 click
elevatorActionQueue.Enqueue(downAction); // call from button 2 click

// Loop through the queue to perform the queued actions
ElevatorAction currentAction = new ElevatorAction();
while(elevatorActionQueue.Count > 0)
{
    currentAction = elevatorActionQueue.Dequeue();
    currentAction.Act();
}
```

Comment: Im trying this on a new blank Form, but when i declare ElevatorAction upAction = new ElevatorAction{ Action = "Up" }; it gives me an error: ...is a field but is used as a type. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ElevatorAction is a class. You need to declare the class first. I've updated my answer to include a skeleton.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a Queue and timer.  You can then use the queue to load the Button text into the queue during the button_click event.  The timer periodically  fires and Deques the Look at [CSharp Queue](http://csharp.net-informations.com/collection/csharp-queue.htm) and [Windows From Timer](http://snipplr.com/view/22250/systemwindowsformstimer-example/) for examples.

```
class Form1 : Form
{
    Queue<string> ButtonQueue = new Queue<string>();
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer theTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        buttonQueue = new Queue();
        theTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(theTimer_Tick);
    }
    private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender.GetType().Name.Equals("Button"))
        {
            buttonQueue.Enqueue(((Button)sender).Text);
        }
    }
    void theTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        theTimer.Enabled = false;

        switch (ButtonQueue.Dequeue().ToUpper())
        {
            case "UP":
                //Run animation include Application.DoEvents() in the animation loop to prevent GUI lockup 
                break;
            case "DOWN":
                //Run animation include Application.DoEvents() in the animation loop to prevent GUI lockup 
                break;
            case "OPEN":
                //Run animation include Application.DoEvents() in the animation loop to prevent GUI lockup 
                break;
        }
        theTimer.Enabled = true;
    }    }
```

Comment: why do you use ButtonQueue and buttonQueue ? i got confused there please explain? furthermore could you explain what you meant with //Run animation include Application.DoEvents(). Sorry for newbie question

Comment: I have tried this, and implemented to correspond with my code, however, my button_click events still overlap, basically the events dont wait for the previous one but start executing straight away.